# Get HTML elements in nested HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

The page has the structure:

```
<html>
 <body>
  ...
  <button class="myclass1" type="button">Continue1</button>
   ...
    #document
     <html>
      <body>
       <button class="myclass" type="button">Continue2</button>
```

How can I click a button Continue2?

I'm trying to use expect-puppeteer. But if you have a solution for puppeteer then I will use it.

```
await expect(page).toClick('button', { text: 'Continue2'}); // not work(Nested html)
await expect(page).toClick('button', { text: 'Continue1'}); // work
```

Comment: Is the nested document part of an iframe?

Comment: <iframe>
 #document

Comment: Can you ID the iFrame somehow?

Comment: yes id="iframe-1"

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect the frame first, then use it instead of `page`. In puppeteer :

```js
const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'iframe-1');
await frame.click('button.myclass');
```